# Can Tor Browser prevent ISP or IT Department at a Work place from knowing what i do while watching a Video online from a work computer (not mine)?

Tags: javascript, webserver, tor, video

I must change the security settings of Tor browser to the lowest to be able to play a Video online, yet i have not tried it till now.

That is why i got to think, whether it is unsafe to play online Videos or play something online that requires javascripts

Comment: Using a work computer is unsafe, Tor or not. The computer could be running a program that takes screenshots of your activity or logs keystrokes, and Tor (or any anonymization tool) won't protect about that.

Comment: @AndréBorie agreed. The other question is also marked as a duplicate so I marked this one as a duplicate of that question.

Comment: I don't see this as a real duplicate since the other questions do not really consider the case that the user is not in full control of the computer. But this is specifically the case here, i.e. *"... from a work computer (not mine)"*. One of these question at least considers use of work network but none considers use of work computer, i.e. a system which should be considered untrusted.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich the answers do cover that case well enough IMO.

Comment: @AndréBorie: you are right that *Can my workplace view my Tor traffic?* does answer it but unfortunately is marked as duplicate to questions which don't care about this important aspect. It might be useful to reopen it (i.e. no longer treat as duplicate) and instead close this one.

Answer (score 2):

If you do it from a work computer it might be that this computer has software installed to monitor your activity. And even when it does not the IT department might at least detect that you are using Tor. And chances are high that you've signed a policy that use of technologies like Tor, VPN or similar is not allowed at work.
But these are just possibilities. It depends a lot on where you live, what kind of policies you have there and how knowledgeable the IT department is.

To summarize: no matter if the system is monitored and no matter if the IT department continuously checks the network for forbidden activity, if there is a policy in place which forbids what you are trying to do then you should not do it if you want to keep your job. Policy violations can also be detected by chance when researching different problems or could be reported by coworkers.

Answer (score 0):

Main video sites will like youtube will have HTML5 support. The only sites that don't have this and you need to downgrade for would probably be porn.

Like Steffen said, if they have monitoring software on the machine it might not matter because they can watch your screen.

If you're really suspicious, boot the PC from a USB stick and use tor there. If you're still paranoid, run a Whonix VM

Comment: If you run a different system than provided on the machine the IT department might detect this too. If one cares about job security one should better check first what is allowed and what not  and prefer personal devices and personal internet to access stuff which is unrelated to work.

Answer (score -1):

This interactive image from [Electronic Frontier Foundation](https://www.eff.org/pages/tor-and-https) will definitely answer your concern and beyond it :
[image]

So the answer is that the **IT Dept (Hacker in the image)** and **Your ISP** **can't see** what you are browsing.

Comment: This graphic does not even consider that the computer used is not in full control of the user which is typical for a system provided by the employer.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich indeed this goes to the core of question, double-check the title :**Can Tor Browser prevent** before downvote.

Comment: If you use Tor Browser on a system which might be monitored by the employer (as in this specific case) the employer can still see what you do, no matter if you use Tor or not. Tor browser requires that the user is in full control of the underlying OS which is usually not the case when using a system at work.

Comment: The OP is obviously using the Tor browser, and this is what he is looking for as an information. Monitored or not this might be a different concern

Comment: But this "different concern" is exactly what the OP is asking about. double-check the title: *...from a work computer (not mine)*.

Comment: in title ***ISP or work computer**, both can monitor on his browsing activity but not his computer.

Comment: I'm not going to make assumptions on his behalf anyway :)